# What's $\bigcap \emptyset$?

Tags: set-theory

http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Intersection_of_Empty_Set

Qeustion1:

First of all, my set-theory is ZFC. So i cannot invoke the *universe* in the proof in the link.

By axiom of Union, $\bigcap \emptyset$ is a set.

Suppose $\exists a\in \bigcap \emptyset$.

Then $\exists A\in \emptyset (a\in A)$, which is false.

Thus, $\neg \exists a\in \bigcap \emptyset$, which implies that it is an emptyset itself.

Where did i go wrong?

Comment: I can't see where you did go wrong: I think you proved $\;\cap\emptyset=\emptyset\;$ , which is funny since in ZFC the empty set is *unique*, so in fact that intersection is just one  unique set: the empty one.

Comment: @DonAntonio isn't $\emptyset$ also unique in NBG? Is the argument in the link wrong? I cannot see where is wrong in the link.

Comment: I don't know about NBG, @Jj- , but you wrote you work within ZFC...

Comment: About the link: I can't fully agree with it yet I understand that what they *actually* meant to do is to talk about an "empty intersection" which, imo, is *not* the same thing. But then again: I'm neither a scholar nor a great lover of this stuff, so...

Comment: I am certain that I have answered this question at least twice before.

Comment: This is very much simply a matter of convention. If we define $\bigcap x$ as $\{t\mid\forall y\in x\,(t\in y)\}$, then $\bigcap\emptyset$ is not a set, as it equals the class of all sets. If we define it as $\{t\in\bigcup x\mid \forall y\in x\,(t\in y)\}$, then $\bigcap\emptyset=\emptyset$. This is of course a minor matter, but you should specify which convention you are using.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In $\sf{ZFC}$, $\bigcap A$ is a notational convenience for the unique class $\mathbf{X}$ (an object in the meta-language) defined by $$\{ x : ( \forall X \in A ) ( x \in X ) \},$$ which is to say that $x \in \bigcap A$ is an abbreviation for the statement $( \forall X \in A ) ( x \in X )$.  One can show (using the Axiom Schema of Separation) that if $\mathbf{A}$ is a *nonempty* class of sets (possibly proper), then $\bigcap \mathbf{A}$ is also a set.

But what about $\bigcap \varnothing$?  Well, given any $x$ the statement $( \forall X \in \varnothing ) ( x \in X )$ is vacuously true, and so $x$ satisfies the condition of being in $\bigcap \varnothing$.  Which is to say that $\bigcap \varnothing$ is the universe of all sets; it is the (proper) class usually denoted $\mathbf{V}$, defined to be $$\{ x : x = x \}.$$  In particular, $\bigcap \varnothing$ is not a set.  (Not a set, that is, unless $\sf{ZFC}$ is inconsistent.  But if $\sf{ZFC}$ is consistent, then essentially by Russell's Paradox we can show that $\mathbf{V}$ is not a set.)

---

One particular troubling point in your proof that $\bigcap \varnothing = \varnothing$ is the following line of reasoning:

> Suppose $\exists a\in \bigcap \emptyset$.
>
> Then $\exists A\in \emptyset (a\in A)$....

Note that this is not part of the definition of the $\bigcap$ notation.

Comment: I have always considered $\bigcap A$ as a set using "Axiom of union and subset schema". Could you please tell me how to prove $\bigcap A$ is a set directly from axiom of specification?

Comment: And yes, it made a typo and i didn't noticed and proceed my argument. Now i see what was wrong

Answer (score 5):

Why "By axiom of union, $\bigcap \emptyset$" is a set?

You only have that $\bigcup\emptyset$ is a set!

Comment: How do i prove that it is not a set?

Comment: @Jj- start by swapping "By axiom of union, $\bigcap\emptyset$ is a set." for "Suppose $\bigcap\emptyset$ exists." Then get a contradiction the usual way.

Answer (score 4):

$x\in\bigcap\varnothing $ iff $x\in A(\forall A\in\varnothing)$. So every set is in $\bigcap\varnothing$.

Comment: Did you mean $\forall A \in \emptyset\,(x\in A)$?